# Alternative to goto in nested loops?

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement, do-while, goto

This code is working fine, however this whole time I've tried avoiding using the `goto` statements that you will see in the switch (`dice_total`) statement.

Without the `goto` statements, the program will not loop back to the beginning of `while (again=='y' || again=='Y')`, and instead it keeps looping itself when it reaches the `do-while` loop.

However, I believe that it is also important to say, that if dice_total is = to the point_total the first time around then the program will function properly, and loop back to the beginning. For example, when the program starts, the first round will generate the point_total, which we will say its 10. Which is a value that will allow the program to continue to the next round, and if the dice_total also gets the same number, 10, the program will say you win, and the loop will work properly. However, if the program reaches the do while loop, and generates a number that isn't 10, but generates a 10 after a few loops, then the program will not loop to the beginning. So what I want to ask, what is wrong with my switch(dice_total) statement, and how can I fix it, to give the program the same effect without using the goto statements?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Declared Variables***********************************
char again = 'y';
int point1;
int point2;
int point_total;
int round_1=1;
int dice1;
int dice2;
int dice_total;
//*****************************************************
//RANDOM SEED******************************************
random_device rd;
mt19937 mt(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<int>dist(1, 6);
//*****************************************************

start://TEMPORARY
while (again == 'y'||again=='Y')
{
    int round_1 = 1;
    system("CLS");
    cout << "WELCOME TO THE CRAPS GAME" << endl;
        cout << "THROWING ROUND:" << round_1 << " DICES.............." << endl;
        point1 = dist(mt);
        point2 = dist(mt);
        point_total = point1 + point2;
        cout << "ROUND: " << round_1 << " First dice is: " << point1 << " and second dice is: " << point2 <<" and the total is:"<<point_total<< endl;
        switch (point_total)
        {
        case 7:
        case 11:
            cout << "YOU WON CONGRATS PRESS Y TO PLAY AGAIN!!" << endl;
            cin >> again;
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 12:
            cout << "YOU LOST, PRESS Y TO TRY AGAIN" << endl;
            cin >> again;
            break;
        default:
            do
            {
                ++round_1;
                cout << "ROUND " << round_1 << endl;
                dice1 = dist(mt);
                dice2 = dist(mt);
                dice_total = dice1 + dice2;
                cout << "THROWING ROUND: " << round_1 << " DICES.............." << endl;
                cout << "ROUND 1 DICE TOTAL IS: " << point_total << endl;
                cout << "ROUND: " << round_1 << " First dice is: " << dice1 << " and second dice is: " << dice2 << " and the total is:" << dice_total << endl;
                switch (dice_total)
                {
                case 11:
                    cout << "YOU WON CONGRATS PRESS Y TO PLAY AGAIN!!" << endl;

                    cin >> again;
                    goto start;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 7:
                case 12:
                    cout << "YOU LOST, PRESS Y TO TRY AGAIN" << endl;

                    cin >> again;
                    goto start;

                default:
                    if (dice_total == point_total)
                    {
                        cout << "YOU WON CONGRATS PRESS Y TO PLAY AGAIN!!<<endl;

                        cin >> again;
                        break;
                    }//if
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Going to next round" << endl;

                    }

                }//dice_total
            }//do
            while (dice_total != point_total);
            break;
        }//switch point
    }//again while
}//main
```

Comment: It may be solved with a combination of `break`, variables and `if` checking the state of those variables, and `continue`. However, what I *really* suggest is to split the code into smaller parts, that you can put into separate functions, and then it's just a matter o assembling the small bits into a larger program, like using small Lego bricks to build something big.

Comment: Everything in that default case should be a function. That function can return a value telling the caller how to behave (break, continue, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is usual when you have too many nested loops *in the same function*, and is an indicator that you need to refactor parts of your code to be in their own functions.

If you do this, then you have more possibilities to control the flow of your code: in each function you have `break` and `return`, and as you can return a custom value, you can use it to determine in the surrounding function if you need to `break` or `return` again.

Besides, this gives you the opportunity to put self-explanatory names to your functions, which makes your code clearer for people that look at it for the first time (as it's written, it's so dense that I can't understand it unless I stare at it for some minutes).

An example of what I mean in code:

### Before

```
int main() {
    start:
    while (a) {
        b1();
        switch(c) {
            case 1:
                do {
                    d();
                    if (cond) goto start;
                } while(e);
            break;
        }
        b2();
    }
}
```

### After

```
int main() {
    while (a) {
        if (!doStuff1())
            break;
    }
    ...
}

bool doStuff1() {
    b1();
    while (a) {
        bool res = doStuff2();
        if (res) return true;
    }
    b2();
    ...
}

bool doStuff2() {
     switch(c) {
         case 1: 
             if (doStuff3()) return true;
     }
     return false;
}

bool doStuff3() {
     do {
         d();
         if (cond) return true;
     } while (e);

     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this design?

```
bool stop=false;
while(!stop && (again == 'y'||again=='Y'))
{
   while(again == 'y'||again=='Y')
   {

        //  ...
        break; /* breaks inner while*/

        //  ...
        stop=true;
        break; /* breaks inner while, and prevents running outer loop*/


   }
}
```